# replacing tub surround: pros and cons glue-up vs direct-to-stud?

Tags: bathtub

i'd like to replace my aging (PVC) tub surround with a sturdier, but inexpensive, multi-panel acrylic (or similar). Noticed those are either glue-up or direct-to-studs. What are the pros and cons of each install method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pros:

Glue up

- wall is flatter, less variance, less warping
- generally easier to install (once prepped/drywall up)
- if going drywall underneath less echo/tin can sound
- on a direct install you must be able to pack the cavity with insulation to prevent push-in and (more) echoes, glue up you don't worry about that
- transition to other parts of the bathroom is easy since drywall to drywall or drywall to backer is really no transition

Direct

- Can have it installed very quickly (no prep)
- don't have to worry about water affecting what is behind it
- the more expensive ones have good transition molding that allows you to install drywall after with small seam to be caulked.